# .htaccess rewritecond rewrite case level 2 folder=info

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wanted to set `.htaccess` to rewrite:

```
example.com/bla/info/
```

to

```
example.com/info/index.php?q=bla

example.com/bla/info/txt/
```

to

```
example.com/info/index.php?q=bla&t=txt
```

I wanted the browser still to display:

```
example.com/bla/info/txt/
```

I didn't want rewrite in the level 2 rewrites, like:

```
example.com/bla/xxx/
```

or

```
example.com/ccc/zzz/aaa/
```

but

```
example.com/silly/info/
```

would work as well as

```
example.com/strange/info/mytxt/
```

Did this make sense?

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start your pattern with ^ and end it with $, the rule will only apply if the whole string matches.

```
RewriteRule   ^/bla/info/$      /info/index.php?q=bla
RewriteRule   ^/bla/info/txt/$  /info/index.php?q=bla&t=txt
```

If you use do not use the [R] option, the URL shown in the browser will be whatever the user entered.

Are you trying to make this general-purpose? If so, you can use regex-type matching and variable substitution.  To make 'bla' match any string up to the next slash (/), use

```
([^/]+)
```

in your pattern and reference it with $1 in your substitution.

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/info/$          /info/index.php?q=$1
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/info/([^/]+)/$  /info/index.php?q=$1&t=$2
```

I recommend the [Apache web pages about mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for more information.

[Edit. Fixed the rules to not include the host name in the pattern, as the original poster figured out.]

--
bmb

Answer (score 0):

you got me in the right track.

i ended up with something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/info/?$ example/info/index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

thanks a lot

Comment: Oops, I forgot the hostname doesn't appear in the pattern. I fixed the answer.